# How to access the 3D cursor with 'Local View' support?

Tags: python, 3d-view

Some scripts use the 3D cursor (for adding new objects or for a point of reference).

A common way to do this is using [bpy.context.scene.cursor_location](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.cursor_location).

However in [Local View](http://blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#local-view) each view has its own cursor, making tools behave strangely when local-view is enabled.

---

So the question is:

What's a good way to access the 3D cursor which will use the cursor as seen by the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of 2 different ways to access the cursor.

Checking the space type and using only 3D views.

```
def context_cursor(context):
    scene = context.scene
    space = context.space_data

    cursor = (space if space and space.type == 'VIEW_3D'
              else scene).cursor_location
    return cursor
```

Using `getattr` with a fallback, however this isn't so reliable since it may return a 2D cursor for the image space (which probably isn't what you want).

```
# don't use this example!
def context_cursor(context):
    cursor = getattr(context.space_data, "cursor_location",
                     context.scene.cursor_location)
    return cursor
```

Note that when the 3D view **isn't** a Local View. `context.space_data.cursor_location`  will use the scene's cursor.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the local view's cursor is the VIEW_3D space's cursor (rather than the context scene's cursor):

```
import bpy
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                print( space.cursor_location )
                break
```

[image]

Comment: Right, pasted the wrong version for some reason, thanks @batFINGER.

Comment: Wonder what voodoo magic ideasman42 has for this one.  I feel context.space_data.cursor_location always gives you the "as seen by the user" cursor loc. when it's the 3D_VIEW type space.  Could set up a bpy.types.Context.cursor_location property that returns such or...